# how add event Click for dynamic tr in table

Tags: jquery

i have html table and add in table row in runtime. i want to add to new tr(dynamic tr) add **ClickEvent**
i write this code, but it's not work

$("#GridView1 tbody tr").click(function (e) {

```
                var id = $(this).find(".lbl").text();
                workOrderId = id;
                //  $("#gridtbl tr").remove();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "PublicHandler.ashx",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { workOrderId: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var grd = $("#gridtbl");
                        $.each(data, function (i, b) {
                            var str = "<tr>";
                            str += "<td style='display: none;'>" + b.WorkId + "</td>";
                            str += "<td>" + b.WorkName + "</td>";
                            str += "<td>" + b.SectionName + "</td>";
                            str += "<td>" + b.SectionSupervisor + "</td>";
                            if (b.RequestCount == null) {
                                str += "<td>" + " " + "</td>";
                            } else {
                                str += "<td>" + b.RequestCount + "</td>";
                            }

                            str += "<td>" + " " + "</td>";

                            str += "</tr>";
                            $(str).click(function () {
                                alert("hiiiiiiiiiii");

                            }).end().appendTo("#gridtbl tr");
                            // grd.append(str);

                        });
                    },
                    dataType: "json"

                });
                popup(e);
            });
```

Comment: you need to use .on() (jQuery 1.7+) or .delegate()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [**`delegate`**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("#GridView1 tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function(e) {
  //rest of the code here
});
```

or lately in jquery 1.7 you can use [**`on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#GridView1 tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e){
    //rest of the code here
});
```

---

as mentioned in the comments by @Matt the [**live**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is [*deprecated*](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/) to its better not to use but i'll leave the example intact

```
  $("#GridView1 tbody tr").live("click",function (e) {
```

Comment: you should probably take live off since it's been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

use the following instead `$("#GridView1 tbody tr").live("click" ,function (e)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not binding a click event to every tr that you add, but looking at the delegate function.

Read more about delegate [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Also people might suggest live, I wouldn't recommend that. Since in your example you always want to bind within the table (which has an unique Id), so instead of making the even listen to the body (which live binds to) you can bind (delegate) it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added Dynamic table..then you can use following code to get row data on row click.
 Note:You can use class name or Id Name of table row instead of 'tr'.

```
  $("body").on('click', 'tr', function () 
   {
          var Name = $(this).find('td:first').text();
          alert(Name);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this also.

```
$.each(data, function (i, b) {
    $tr = $('<tr />', {
        id : <tr_id>,
        on : {
            click : function (e) {
                // here goes the click event logic
            }
        }
    }).appendTo("#gridtbl");
});
```